# How specify caption to column in oracle and read it from C# through ODP.Net?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

With `ODP.Net` package we fill a simple query result into `Dataset` by `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter`.I want to have a bit more description for resulting columns. Would have been nice if I could define a caption for columns in `Oracle` and get them in the resulting dataset.

I found a way to add a comment on column in `Oracle` :

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_columns IS 'MY_CUSTOM_CAPTION'
```

but I don't know how we can get it.

In the other side i found two options (`Caption` & `Extended properties`) in the resulting dataset which i guess is what i am looking for, but it seems that I am wrong:( :

[image]

Anyone knows a way to put some description or alternative caption to columns in Oracle DB and read them in application by `Odp.Net`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible ways you can choose.

1. Read the Column comments from Oracle as you described in your question
2. Create a own Table where you store extra information

In both ways you need to join an extra Table to your query. If you want to read the Column comments take a look at [Dba_col_comments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3074.htm#REFRN23040). This table stores all columncomments you define in your Oracledatabase. So you can read them with sql. But be careful that you don't fill Column comments with extra information which describe the column. You DBA and others will intend that a column comment describe for what the column is or what it stores. So don't write any other information to it.

The second approach is that you build an own Table, where you store extra information for your columns. You just need three columns for table, column and information. This table you can join.

Comment: The way that you mentioned ,absolutely will work perfect. but we can't modify our queries or procedures to add the description table result! At least now, is not possible (Think of the thousands of cases)! I prefer using some built-in facilities to met our expectation as soon as possible.

Comment: Will be difficult to change something if you cannot change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a view from your table like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_my_table AS
SELECT my_column AS "My Caption even with spaces"
FROM my_table;
```

You can also make DML operations like DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT into such views.